# Cartthrob and Transcribe: orders don't get the default language assigned

Tags: channel-entries, cartthrob, transcribe

I was wondering why my CT invoices are always empty. When digging deeper I noticed that a simple

```
{exp:channel:entries  channel="orders" status="not none" }
    {if no_results}This invoice could not be found{/if}
    Entry ID: {entry_id}<br />
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

doesn't even return the no_results branch.

After some more testing it was clear that all CT generated channel entries, i.e. orders and purchased_items, don't have the default language assigned to the channel entry. After manually changing the language the channel entries can be found and invoices get generated as they should.

Question is... is this a CT or a Transcribe bug? Or is there even a configuration setting which I may have missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling transcribe was the solution:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
     channel="orders" 
     limit="1" 
     status="not none" 
     dynamic="no" 
     entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" 
     parse_inward="yes" 
     show_future_entries="yes" 
     transcribe="disable"}
```